# better alternative for tcp_syncookies in linux

Tags: tcp, connection, ddos, syn, tcp-window-scaling

In an effort to prevent DDOS attacks I followed suggestions to leave /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies value set to 1 in my linux box to enable TCP syncookies.

However, when I look at this URL: http://ckdake.com/content/2007/disadvantages-of-tcp-syn-cookies.html

It tells me that if I enable tcp_syncookies then half the tcp features including large window management will be disabled which could then reduce performance.

I read elsewhere that part of the purpose of syn cookies is to expand a tcp syn backlog buffer beyond its upper limit (via /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog) when more packets come in so packets don't drop.

I want to be able to disable syn cookies so I can take full advantage of tcp and make my server run faster and continue to not have DDOS attacks. I can easily increase the syn buffer and the maximum connections but I think theres a point where I'll run out of memory if I go too high.

Does anyone have a good alternative method to syn cookies on a heavy server without potentially being attacked by DDOS? I want to enjoy features of TCP and serve content very fast to users.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 10.04 has default "sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf" setting below:

```
# Turn on SYN-flood protections.  Starting with 2.6.26, there is no loss
# of TCP functionality/features under normal conditions.  When flood
# protections kick in under high unanswered-SYN load, the system
# should remain more stable, with a trade off of some loss of TCP
# functionality/features (e.g. TCP Window scaling).
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
```

Comment: Why do you mention Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Because I do not confirm that other distributions include this config in default or not.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, tcp_syncookies introduces more benefits than disadvantages.

Instead of the typical speculation on random blogs, perhaps we could consult "[the source](https://lwn.net/Articles/277146/)":

> With the updates for IPv6 and modern TCP option schemes syncookies
>   appear primed to keep providing sweet relief in their somewhat
>   esoteric networking security niche.

The [linked article](https://lwn.net/Articles/277146/) quotes some experiments and draws some conclusions:

> Willy Tarreau: My tests on an AMD LX800 with max_syn_backlog at 63000
>   on an HTTP reverse proxy consisted in injecting 250 hits/s of
>   legitimate traffic with 8000 SYN/s of noise.[..] Without SYN cookies,
>   the average response time was about 1.5 second and unstable (due to
>   retransmits), and the CPU was set to 60%. With SYN cookies enabled,
>   the response time dropped to 12-15ms only, but CPU usage jumped to
>   70%. The difference appears at a higher legitimate traffic rate.
>
> Ross Vandegrift: Under no SYN flood, the server handles 750 HTTP
>   requests per second, measured via httping in flood mode. With a
>   default tcp_max_syn_backlog of 1024, I can trivially prevent any
>   inbound client connections with 2 threads of syn flood. Enabling
>   tcp_syncookies brings the connection handling back up to 725 fetches
>   per second.
>
> This data compellingly supports the continued value of the syncookie
>   and that position seems to have won the day. The IPv6 syncookie
>   patches are now queued within the network 2.6.26 development tree.

Also, according to CentOS' [documentation](https://www.centoshowtos.org/network-and-security/tcp_syncookies/), this is used in an adaptive way, possibly in order to avoid disrupting legitimate traffic:

> **If** the number set in tcp_max_syn_backlog is reached, this parameter
>   kicks in so that your server isn't unreachable due to connections
>   waiting for an ACK that will never come.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the file /etc/sysctl.conf, run:

```
# vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append the following entry:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
```

Save and close the file. To reload the change, type:

```
# sysctl -p
```

Comment: Or, to try out the setting without making it permanent in a config file: `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1`. (Your answer is relevant for a typical visitor here, but would better be a comment on the question as it does not answer the question itself. I guess is that's why somebody downvoted.)